# how to install anaconda / miniconda on Linux silently

Tags: linux, anaconda, miniconda

How do I install the anaconda / miniconda without prompts on Linux command line?

Is there a way to pass `-y` kind of option to agree to the T&Cs, suggested installation location etc. by default?

Comment: Yes, `bash miniconda.sh -b`. I think typing `bash miniconda.sh --help` would have mentioned that, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 44, accepted):

can be achieved by `bash miniconda.sh -b`  (thanks [@darthbith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338902/how-to-silently-install-anaconda-miniconda-on-linux?noredirect=1#comment85688510_49338902))

The command line usage for this can only be seen with `-h` flag but not `--help`, so I missed it.

To install the anaconda to another place, use the `-p` option:

```
bash anaconda.sh -b -p /some/path
```

Comment: a common parameter is -p PREFIX, eg,
`sh miniconda.sh -b -p /usr/local/miniconda`

Comment: @kevad how can you ensure the relevant changes to PATH will be automatically handled in a silent install? It doesn't appear to update path natively without user prompt.

Comment: @Chayapol Indeed, when installing within a Singularity image, `-p /usr/local/miniconda` was critical to avoid it being installed in the root directory where I can't reach it.

Comment: what does the -b option do ?

Comment: @moth It means batch mode. So it doesn't ask any questions, opposite of interactive (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138499).

Answer (score 2):

Silent installation can be done like this, but it doesn't update the `PATH` variable so you can't run it after the installation with a short command like `conda`:

```
cd /tmp/
curl -LO https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -u
```

Here `-b` means batch/silent mode, and `-u` means update the existing installation of Miniconda at that path, rather than failing.

You need to run additional commands to initialize `PATH` and other shell init scripts, e.g. for Bash:

```
source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate
conda init bash
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick installation of miniconda silently I use a wrapper
script [script](https://gist.github.com/mherkazandjian/cce01cf3e15c0b41c1c4321245a99096) that can be executed from the terminal without
even downloading the script. It takes the installation destination path
as an argument (in this case `~/miniconda`) and does some validation too.

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mherkazandjian/cce01cf3e15c0b41c1c4321245a99096/raw/03c86dae9a212446cf5b095643854f029b39c921/miniconda_installer.sh | bash -s -- ~/miniconda
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) let you install `anaconda`/`miniconda`

(after successful instalation)

```
pyenv install --list
pyenv install miniconda3-4.3.30
```